# What is an efficient way to combine 2 numbers to use as the key of an object?

Tags: javascript, performance, dictionary, data-structures, hash

I am using the following pattern to index an injection from pairs of numbers to numbers:

```
var myHash = {};
...
for (... billion of iterations ...)
    var x = someNum;
    var y = otherNum;
    myHash[x + "," + y] = z;
```

The problem with this code is that I'm using a string as the key of `myHash`, which has been tested to be **much** slower than integer keys. My question is: what is a more intelligent way to combine 2 numbers before using them as keys of an object? I.E., how to combine 2 doubles into an unique Integer?

Comment: Why not just use a 2-dimensional array?

Comment: How exactly? Remember I have arbitrary double values.

Comment: Oh, if they're doubles, the way you're doing it is probably best. It's pretty weird to use floating point values as keys, though, because they're approximate and you might not get the exact same values when you later need to look things up.

Comment: I think it will be difficult to map any 2 double-precision numbers into integers, unless you put some sort of constraints on the input.  What do the numbers represent (if anything)?

Comment: I'd be curious to see your testing. In JS, all keys are strings, so I wouldn't think it would make a difference.

Comment: It does, because V8 and other engines optimize hashes when you only use integer keys. Those numbers can be anything since they are unboxed values for a lisp runtime. That is, they can be actual doubles, tagged pointers, anything. No pattern whatsoever. I know this sounds tricky but if anyone has an insight I'd really appreciate, that particular function is for auto memoization, which sped up all my benchmarks that didn't use doubles almost 6-fold. Using those string keys (for double) support pretty much negates the whole speedup of the auto memoization... for such a lame reason!

Comment: use decimals as keys.. no loss will occur. please reffer to this fiddle for a clear demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ymzrocks/kngj4549/1/

Comment: Decimals in JavaScript? ECMAScript is clear, all numbers are doubles.

Comment: @sixfingeredman: Viclib is correct, the integer case is heavily optimised, even if `Object.keys([1])` is `["0"]`. See [integer vs non-integer indexing comparison](http://jsperf.com/integral-keys-vs-non-integral-keys), derived from [array vs object comparison](http://jsperf.com/performance-of-array-vs-object). Both show that indexing with non-integral keys is much slower.

Comment: @Amadan: I see. I didn't realize he meant an ordered numeric iteration.

Comment: @sixfingeredman: He didn't, it is just the easiest way to set up the test. While the test does leave a possibility that specifically the sequential integral access is optimised, I would be surprised if that was the case; rather, I believe it is just integral access (i.e. "array keys", from the definition quoted by Alexis Wilke below) that is treated differently from other keys.

Answer (score 2):

There is the definition of an array in JavaScript:

> Array objects give special treatment to a certain class of property names. A property name P (in the form of a String value) is an array index if and only if `ToString(ToUint32(P))` is equal to P and `ToUint32(P)` is not equal to 2<sup>32</sup> - 1. A property whose property name is an array index is also called an element. Every Array object has a length property whose value is always a nonnegative integer less than 2<sup>32</sup>. The value of the length property is numerically greater than the name of every property whose name is an array index; whenever a property of an Array object is created or changed, other properties are adjusted as necessary to maintain this invariant. Specifically, whenever a property is added whose name is an array index, the length property is changed, if necessary, to be one more than the numeric value of that array index; and whenever the length property is changed, every property whose name is an array index whose value is not smaller than the new length is automatically deleted. This constraint applies only to own properties of an Array object and is unaffected by length or array index properties that may be inherited from its prototypes.

In other words, if the index you specify is a number representing an integer between 0 and 0xFFFFFFFE, then it is used as an array index. Any other value is taken as a string and it is used to create an object member instead of an array item.

So if you have constraints on your indices which would fit the valid range (0 to 0xFFFFFFFE) then you're good. Otherwise, what you have is probably the fastest.

So the following represents string indices which are members of object `myHash`:

```
myHash[x + "," + y] = z;
```

Someone mentioned using an array of arrays. That would not help you. You'd get many arrays instead of many strings. It would probably be about the same if not slower. The idea is something like this:

```
myHash[x] = [];  // initialize the sub-array (must be done only once per value of 'x'
myHash[x][y] = z;   // save z in that array
```

I do not recommend the double array because it will initialize one array for each value of 'x' on top of myHash and that probably not any faster than having the string concatenation (especially because you'll have to test whether the myHash[x] array was already defined or not...).

So... it is possible to write:

```
myHash[3.3] = "that worked?";
```

But if after that you check out the length, you'll notice it is zero:

```
console.log("Hash length = " + myHash.length);
```

This is because `3.3` is not an integer.

Comment: This isn't a very clear answer. Might want to focus on the mapping doubles to ints thing, maybe provide some examples.

Comment: I thought that the integer thing, `ToString(ToUint32(P)) == P`, would be enough to explain how the value is checked and accepted as an integer. The mapping itself is not an `Array` thing, though. It's part of the Object instead.

Comment: I actually find it a pretty clear and informative answer... it just doesn't give any new / creative solution, but that is fine and might help future readers.